# why <mat-pseudo-checkbox> automatically created

Tags: checkbox, angular-material, migration, pseudo-element, mat-select

We recently migrated to Angular 17 from v15. For all the drop downs in ,  is automatically created and the tick mark is seen for the option selected. Can someone advise how to remove these pseduo checkboxes. I don't see any documentation for pesudo-checkbox anywhere including in material.angular.io.
Thanks a lot.
Vijay

I tried by putting mat-pseudo-checkbox by applying style display: none but didn't worked.

Comment: Check whether your code have "mat-select multiple" https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples#select-multiple instead of mat-select